# How to create a validation like this $ {param1 }> ${param2} in a RouteOnAttribute in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

How can I do in nifi a validation for a RouteOnAttribute like this: `${param1} > ${param2}`, these parameters are dates in unix format. The error that I currently have is the normal one (it is not valid because several expressions were found but only 1 was expected).
Basically, what I need is that if one parameter is greater than another, the workflow goes to one side, otherwise it goes to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`gt`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#gt) function:

```
${ param1:gt(param2) }
```